# Windows Authentication deployment on IIS Server, windows login prompts keep coming, how to stop it?

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, iis-8.5

I'm trying to use Windows Authentication and get Email Id of currently logged in user on Windows in ASP.Net MVC 5.
But, I always get login prompt when trying to access using IP, it seems to be working fine for localhost on the server.

My Web.Config entries are

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows"/>     
<identity impersonate="true" />    
</system.web>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>               
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" useKernelMode="true">
                <providers>
                    <clear />
                    <add value="NTLM" />
                    <add value="Negotiate" />
                </providers>
                <extendedProtection tokenChecking="Allow" />
            </windowsAuthentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />

        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

- Apllication Pool: Classic with 4.0
- .Net Version in Code: 4.5
- IIS Manager: 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2
- IIS Server is on different domain( Azure) w.r.t. client (MyDomain.com)

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Manager Settings in the Server set the Windows Authentication Enabled and Form Authentication Disabled.